# Http session and @ViewScoped map location

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I was thinking of switching to a distributed key-value store for http session data when suddenly `@ViewScoped` beans came to my mind. They also persist their state of the view in a `Map<String, Object>` which can be reached by `getViewRoot().getViewMap()` and which must be also the subject for distributed persistence in my case.

The things would be much easier if this map was the part of http session data (as some people say), but I can't find any evidences that it **must** be kept there and that it's location isn't up to implementation providers.

Could someone with in-depth knowledge of JSF2 please shed some light on this subject?

Comment: Refer to [Communication in JSF 2: Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes) to get a better understanding of `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, BalusC says they are in session, how do I know that it's not mojarra-specific? I'd appreciate reference to a spec.

Comment: You can [download the JSF spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245) and see it by yourself. Anyway, MyFaces has not documented [`UIViewRoot#getViewMap`](http://myfaces.apache.org/core21/myfaces-api/apidocs/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewMap()) as expected, so we can't be sure how they do it. Still, what's your real problem?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, JSP has nothing to do with my question. My problem is to find JSR which would say something about persistence of the view map - it must reside in session or it's up to the implementation

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. Here's the good one: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314